# Update Access Query: Switching out certain characters

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have an Access sheet that contains a bunch of names.  I just made a Username column that takes the persons last name and adds the first two letters of their first name to the end.  For instance John Smith becomes SmithJo.  The problem is some people use initials for their first name (example: A.J.)

My query is taking the period in their first name and using it in the Username column.  So A.J. Smith looks like this SmithA. Instead, I  would like it to take the that second letter instead of the period (but only for those that have initials as their first name). So the username should read SmithAJ

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Use Replace function to firsts eliminate periods.

Comment: Do some people use only one initial for their first name? More variations? In general, go with June7's idea above, start with a query that adjusts the first name data so you have something to work with.